# Existence of solution to $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Given a polynomial $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, $a \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, I would like to classify all primes $p$ so that there exists $\alpha \in \Bbb{F}_p$ in which $f(\alpha) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$.

This can be done in the case of quadratic equations, in which quadratic reciprocity is the answer. Is there a similarly simple method of checking if $f(x)$ has a root mod $p$?

Comment: Classification will be a tall order. You can still use the discriminant though. There are no solutions if and only if $f(x)$ is irreducible. When that happens, the Galois group is cyclic of order three, implying that the discriminant is a quadratic residue. So if the discriminant is a quadratic non-residue, then there will be a solution.

Comment: For large $p$ the definite test for presence of solutions is to calculate $\gcd(f(x),x^p-x)$. This is relatively quick with square-and-multiply. There are zeros iff the gcd is not constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the discriminant of your cubic polynomial is a square $Disc(f) \in \Bbb{Q}^{*2}$  or if $f$ is reducible then it is close to the quadratic case, otherwise it gets much more complicated : the Galois group of the splitting field is $S_3$ and it is the first instance of class field theory (and for negative discriminant elliptic curves with complex multiplication).

Your question becomes the characterization of the non-abelian Artin L-function $L(s,\rho)=\zeta_K(s)/\zeta(s)$ where $K=\Bbb{Q}[x]/(f)$, class field theory will say that $L(s,\rho) = L(s,\psi)$ where $\psi$ is an Hecke character of $F$, relating the factorization of $f\bmod p$ with the norm and ideal class of the primes of $\Bbb{Z}+\Delta O_F$ above $p$.

On the web there are several detailed examples about $x^3+x+1$ but I never recall how to find them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Regarding the case where the discriminant is a square, I would like to understand better what you mean by it is close to the quadratic case. Do you mind answering it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734894/find-prime-p-which-x3-ax-b-equiv-0-pmodp-has-a-root-with-square-dis)?